# Is it possible to automaticly restart program in GDB after exception (segfault) error?

Tags: c++, file, logging, gdb

How I can run a program in C++ with GDB so that in case of error exception (segfaults) restarted the program (I want that GDB automatically use "run" command), and at the same time any errors logged to a file (command "where").

Is it at possible?

Answer (score 5):

Let me show you an example that restarts a program for 3 times in case it crashes. I use a python script to handle SIGSEGV (https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Events-In-Python.html).

First, this is an example of a GDB session:

```
>gdb -q -x restart.py ./a.out
Reading symbols from /home/a.out...done.
process id: 1700

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040060e in c () at main2.cpp:9
9         *ptr = *ptr +1;
#0  0x000000000040060e in c () at main2.cpp:9
#1  0x000000000040062a in main () at main2.cpp:15
process id: 1704

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040060e in c () at main2.cpp:9
9         *ptr = *ptr +1;
#0  0x000000000040060e in c () at main2.cpp:9
#1  0x000000000040062a in main () at main2.cpp:15
process id: 1705

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040060e in c () at main2.cpp:9
9         *ptr = *ptr +1;
#0  0x000000000040060e in c () at main2.cpp:9
#1  0x000000000040062a in main () at main2.cpp:15
process id: 1706

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040060e in c () at main2.cpp:9
9         *ptr = *ptr +1;
#0  0x000000000040060e in c () at main2.cpp:9
#1  0x000000000040062a in main () at main2.cpp:15
(gdb)
```

For each crash a file with a name crash.file.PID is created. This is an example of a file:

```
>more crash.file.1860
#0  0x000000000040060e in c () at main2.cpp:9
#1  0x000000000040062a in main () at main2.cpp:15
```

This is a C++ program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int c()
{
  printf("process id: %d\n", getpid());
  int *ptr =0;
  *ptr = *ptr +1;
  return *ptr;
}

int main()
{
  c();
  return 0;
}
```

This is a python script:

```
>cat restart.py
#!gdb
import sys
import gdb
import os

number_restarts = 3

def on_stop(sig):
  global number_restarts
  if isinstance(sig, gdb.SignalEvent) and sig.stop_signal == "SIGSEGV":
    crash_file = "crash.file." + str( gdb.selected_inferior().pid)
    gdb.execute("set logging file " + crash_file)
    gdb.execute("set logging on")
    gdb.execute("where")
    gdb.execute("set logging off")
    if (number_restarts > 0):
      number_restarts -= 1
      gdb.execute("set confirm off")
      gdb.execute("kill")
      gdb.execute("run")


gdb.events.stop.connect (on_stop)
gdb.execute("set pagination off")
gdb.execute("run")
```

Comment: If c program requires command-line args, then it will be given via gdb.execute("run --args") in restart.py file.